Message Code: CMN_1022 Message: Database driver error...in Informatica Powercenter
enter image description hereWorkflow is failing with this error: Database Driver error ....
while executing Presql query. and it fails once/twice in a week around 8-9am in the morning and continues to run all other days in a cyclic order.
FYI...In Production, the same workflow doesn't fail at all. only the issue is in PreProd environment..
Any idea on this on how this can be resolved?

what is the error details you got ? There can be several reason - 1. the pre-prod have low hardware(CPU,Mem) so its not able to support pre SQL. Pls note Pre SQL is applied as a  whole SQL and not in chunks. 2. SQL has some date filter which processes more data over weekends 3. DB undergoing maintainance (?). 4. Fire the SQL manually when infa jobs failing and see what is the outcome.

For Reason 1: except during the 8-9am window, all other times, The workflow runs as normal.  Reason-3: I'm checking with DBA about any activity during that window. Raeson 4: After the job fails, I usually triggerd the job manually and the workflow runs successful. I have attached the pic.

You may be right, some other job is consuming all resources during 8-9AM. If you cant find anything conclusive,  you can split your delete statement in 2 or 4 parts. Instead of deleting 2 years of data, try 1 year at a time or may be 6months at a time. Or you can avoid running your flow between 8-9AM

I will try with that... thanks Koushik
